# I want to make a friendly url with .htaccess without using any id

Tags: php

```
www.example.com/tour_detail/angkor-songsaa-luxury-private-island-honeymoon-premium-tour-19-105.html
```

Note : 19-105 is id, so i don't want it show like that i just want

```
www.exmaple.com/tour_detail/angkor-songsaa-luxury-private-island-honeymoon-premium-tour
```

Comment: Mean that I don't want to show id with url

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^angkor-songsaa-luxury-private-island-honeymoon-premium-tour/?$    angkor-songsaa-luxury-private-island-honeymoon-premium-tour-19-105.html    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for your url
```

If you want to read more: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/